# Focused Highlighting of list items based on mouse scroll increments

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom, mouseevent

I have a drop down menu where I need list items to be highlighted based on the mouse scroll increments. When the user hovers over the list and scrolls 1x up or down, the item immediately above or below should be highlighted. This involves getting the deltaY of the mousescroll event I believe. The problem is that this deltaY value is super sensitive. So when there's even a slight scroll up gesture, it logs it as something crazy like 7x/8x. How should I approach handling this functionality.

This is what I currently have (but feel free to suggest something completely different if it'll work better):

***(also, (event.target.id[event.target.id - 1]) this isn't working. what am I doing wrong?)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

highlightListItem(event: any, scrollUp?: boolean, scrollDown?: boolean): void {
    this.highlightTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.someService.highlightListItem(event.target.id);
    }, 450);
    if (scrollUp) {
      this.highlightListItem = setTimeout(() => {
        this.someService.highlightListItem(event.target.id[event.target.id - 1]);
      }, 450)
    } else if (scrollDown) {
      this.highlightTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.someService.highlightTimer(event.target.id[event.target.id - 1]);
      }, 450);
    }


  scrollEvent(event: any): void {
    console.log(event.deltaY * 100);
    if (event.deltaY < 0) {
      this.highlightListItem(event, false, true);
    } else if (event.deltaY > 0) {
      this.highlightListItem(event, true, false);
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```html
  <mat-card class="some-card" *ngFor="let property of properties; let i = index;" id="segment{{i}}"
                (mousewheel)="scrollEvent($event)">
                <mat-card-content class="some-table">
                    <div class="index">{{i + 1 }}</div>
                    <div class="someClass">
                        <div>{{property.field}}</div>
                    </div>
                </mat-card-content>
   </mat-card>
```

Comment: @nhminshaq share a jsfiddle or codepen as an example?

Comment: Hey Naren, thanks for responding. Found a good jsfiddle example that returns element visibility while scrolling..Knowing that value helped in selecting the next element in the array and transition to it smoothly.

Here's the jsfiddle if anyone's interested: http://jsfiddle.net/b63rH/